# We are "here" or "there"

Tags: word-choice

What would someone say when they are telling someone that they have arrived at their destination.

Is it:

> We are **here** now

or:

> We are **there** now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is the location of *we*, so use *here*.

> We are **here** now.

For a different topic, it might be different. For example if you told someone:

> We had trouble finding that store, but we are **there** now.

It is OK to use *there* when the topic is a specific location you traveled to.

Answer (score 0):

In my dialect we say:

**We're there**

to mean we have arrived at a remote destination, and

**We're here**

when speaking to someone, to mean we have arrived where that person is awaiting us or has planned to meet us.